# Syntax for class filter patterns

Tags: intellij-idea

I don't understand the syntax of the patterns used in IntelliJ IDEA's menu `Run | View Breakpoints... | Catch class filter | Include | Add pattern...` and probably many other places in the IDE.

Why does the pattern `com.myname.*Tests` not match `com.myname.mypackage.Tests`?

| Include pattern | Is com.mypackage.Tests included? |
| --- | --- |
| com.myname.mypackage.Tests | true |
| com.myname.* | true |
| *Tests | true |
| com.myname.*Tests | false |

Note that I also unsuccessfully tried:

- com.myname.**.Tests
- com.myname.*.Tests
- com.myname..*.Tests
- com.myname.**.*.Tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not clear from the UI or documentation:

`*` in the middle is not supported. Regular expressions here are limited to exact matches and patterns that begin with `*` or end with `*`, for example, `*.Foo` or `java.*`.